# get models fields after save

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have model with these fields : [image] Now when the model is saved I wanted to show those fields in the Hospital Pack tab in the following format : [image]

How do I do this ? I am using django admin panel.

Suppose I have Worker model :

```
class Worker(SoftDeleteModel):
    resident = models.ForeignKey(ResidentIdentification, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    worker_type = {
        ('GP', 'GP'),
        ('Social_worker', 'Social Worker'),
    }
    worker = models.CharField(
        "Type", max_length=20, choices=worker_type, blank=True, null=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    fax = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'GP/Social Worker/Other'
        verbose_name_plural = 'GP/Social Worker/Others'
```

Now when this model is saved via admin panel and when goto HospitalPack tab as in the image, I wanted to show those saved model fields and similarly other model fields as well.

Comment: I guess what you want is to be able to edit your values, is that right? It's hard to tell if that's what you want and if so, please provide your models.py and admin.py

Comment: @HigorRossato I don't want to edit the model values. I just wanted to display the saved model like in the second image above

Comment: Can you provide your models.py and your admin.py? Where do you wanna display that? In the admin? I still have a hard time to understand your question

Comment: the screenshot you show isn't from the admin panel (django admin). Are you saying that the model is created/edited in a custom view and in the admin you only want view the model? In that case, just make all fields readonly_fields.

Comment: @HigorRossato I wanted to display in the inline tab in admin panel.

Comment: @dirkgroten that is admin panel customized with django jet. I haven't use custom view and all, it's purely in admin panel

Comment: So you want to be able to add a new entry, but never to edit it again after it was added?